# Make CSV file from each row

Tags: python, database, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have a dataframe with n columns. One is the city name.

I am trying to extract each row(s) based on city name and print each to a new CSV file.

```
col1  col2    cityName

a       5     Madrid
s       10    NEWYORK
d       0     London
f       2     Berlin
```

Answer:

**first csv file:**

```
col1  col2    cityName

a       5     Madrid
```

**second csv file:**

```
col1  col2    cityName
s       10    NEWYORK
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code will iterate over any DataFrame(if exists) and create a new csv file(for every row) containing the column header as well as the row or else if the DataFrame doesn't exist it will not do anything.

```py
import pandas as pd
i=0
while True:
    try: 
        df.iloc[[i]].to_csv("filename.csv")
        i = i+1
    except: pass
```

Comment: Explain a bit more about your answer.

Comment: This code will iterate over any DataFrame(if exists) and create a new csv file(for every row) containing the column header as well as the row or else if the DataFrame doesn't exist it will not do anything.

Comment: I mean, edit the answer, and explain it there: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer

Answer (score 1):

You can group rows by cityName column and then export to separate csv every group like this:

EDIT: add save results to csv files

EDIT: add zip all files

```
import zipfile
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(
    data={'col1': ['a', 's', 'd', 'f', 'x'], 'col2': [5, 10, 0, 2, 4],
          'cityName': ['Madrid', 'NEWYORK', 'London', 'Berlin', 'Madrid']})

groupby = df.groupby('cityName')
out_zip = zipfile.ZipFile("58377674.zip", "w")

for n, g in groupby:
    print(n)
    csv = g.to_csv(index=False)
    print(csv)
    csv_filename = "{}.csv".format(n)
    with open(csv_filename, 'w') as out_file:
        out_file.write(csv)
    out_zip.write(csv_filename)
```

Comment: I have each group in my output, how can I send each to an Excel file?

Comment: @Narg add save files

Comment: Can you also tell how I can make zip file from all  csv = g.to_csv(index=False)?

Comment: @NData, add zip all files. You can add `import os` and add `os.remove(csv_filename)` at the end to remove CSV files

Answer (score -1):

The Following code will make a CSV file, and write a row in that. You can iterate over this code till your last record, and each time it will make a unique data file.

```
import csv
from datetime import datetime

for index, row in dataframe.iterrows():
    filename = datetime.now()
    filename = filename.strftime("%d-%m-%Y_%H:%M:%S")
    file = open('data_'+str(filename)+'.csv', 'w')
    w = csv.writer(file)
    w.writerow([row['col1'], row['col2'], row['cityName']])
    file.close()
```

Comment: The question is underspecified. Your answer does not solve anything for a dataframe. It does not produce the "asked for" files, it contains unspecified names => NameError and does not use a contexthandling `with open(..) as f:` which is the desired way to work with files